# Java Entity Intersection

Tags: java, intersection

I'm checking an intersection of an entity with an entity. My method is:

```
public boolean intersects(Entity e) {
    int r1x1 = this.posPoint.x;
    int r1x2 = this.posPoint.x + texture.w;
    int r2x1 = e.posPoint.x;
    int r2x2 = e.posPoint.x + e.texture.w;

    int r1y1 = this.posPoint.y;
    int r1y2 = this.posPoint.y + texture.h;
    int r2y1 = e.posPoint.y;
    int r2y2 = e.posPoint.y + e.texture.h;
    // ALTEA!
    return ((r1x2 >= r2x1) && (r1y2 >= r2y1) && (r1x1 <= r2x2) && (r1y1 <= r2y2));
}
```

How am I able to get the Point/Point Array were the entites intersect?

BigTeddy

Answer (score 1):

> How am I able to get the Point/Point Array were the entites intersect?

I'm not sure why you want an Array?  If you want to know whether two points are intersecting, use the [Distance Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance).